# JSONPath Error: Unable to Parse Token max()

Tags: json, error-handling, token, jsonpath

I am using Jsonpath to get data from the Json Data. I am having trouble and facing unexpected behavior of this query. Following is my data I want to get the max value of longestCall and my query is `max($.Items[*].longestCall)` this query Returns the maximum value at https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ but at https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ error appears.

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "queueName": "basic",
            "totalNumberOfCalls": 100,
            "longestCall": 10,
            "queueSLA": 50
        },
        {
            "queueName": "inBound-inq",
            "totalNumberOfCalls": 120,
            "longestCall": 11,
            "queueSLA": 60
        },
        {
            "queueName": "support-inq",
            "totalNumberOfCalls": 200,
            "longestCall": 15,
            "queueSLA": 65
        },
        {
            "queueName": "verification-inq",
            "totalNumberOfCalls": 80,
            "longestCall": 13,
            "queueSLA": 70
        },
        {
            "queueName": "booking-inq",
            "totalNumberOfCalls": 105,
            "longestCall": 14,
            "queueSLA": 75
        }
    ]
}
```

I am a newbie with JSONPath, please help me here I would really appreciate that!

Comment: This is a software developers resource, not a web site testing one

Answer (score 0):

On the last few comments people were not very friendly, That's not how Stack overflow is supposed to be.

I did some tests on both websites and the problem seems to be with https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ and not your query.